# How to make status bar scrollable and fit on top

Tags: android, material-design

How to make status bar scrollable and how to fit it at top?

I want to make scrollable status bar when I scroll it fits at top of the activity so please help me how to do the same thing.

any suggestion is welcome.

I want to make status bar scrollable like this :

[image]

When I scroll bottom it fits at top like this :

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `Toolbar` in `AppBarLayout` and use `CoordinatorLayout` like a parent. A good guide about this you can find [here](http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)